# How to change column order (sort) in pandastic way?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe with header that is list of 'string-integers':

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'1': [1, 2], '7': [3, 4], '3': [3, 4], '5': [2, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   1  3  5  7
0  1  3  2  3
1  2  4  7  4
```

This code change order of column (sort):

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = [int(x) for x in cols]
cols.sort()
cols = [str(x) for x in cols]
df = df[cols]

   1  3  5  7
0  1  3  2  3
1  2  4  7  4
```

I'm not happy with this solution. Of course, I can hide it in the function, but probably more elegant approach exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options depending on what you require.

**Option 1**

You can use `sort_values` to sort as strings:

```
df.columns = df.columns.sort_values()
```

Note this means that "10" will appear *before* "2".

**Option 2**

If you wish to convert to integers and then sort:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int).sort_values()
```

**Option 3**

If you want to keep as string, but order by integer value:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int).sort_values().astype(str)
```

A pure Python approach is also possible:

```
df.columns = sorted(df, key=int)
```

Comment: Option 1 - could be misleading, see `d = {'1': [1, 2], '7': [3, 4], '3': [3, 4], '31': [2, 7]}` gives order 1, 3, 31,7. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @QuantChristo, Yes, agreed. That's why I clarified *sort as strings*. I'll add an additional disclaimer.